# Change in string some part, but without one part - where are numbers

Tags: c#, string, replace

For example I have such string:

```
ex250-r-ninja-08-10r_
```

how could I change it to such string?

```
ex250 r ninja 08-10r_
```

as you can see I change all - to space, but didn't change it where I have `XX-XX` part... how could I do such string replacement in c# ? (also string could be different length)

I do so for -

```
string correctString = errString.Replace("-", " ");
```

but how to left - where number pattern XX-XX ?

Comment: `XX-XX` part can be only numbers? It could be like `ab-cd` ?

Comment: @SonerGönül yes, only digit

Comment: Will there ever be a "-" at the start of the string?

Comment: @JonSkeet what do you mean?  rigth is ex250 r ninja 08-10r_  not -ex250 r ninja 08-10r_

Comment: I mean will the input string ever be something like "-xyz ninja 10-10-"? If it *did* have hyphens at the start or end, what would you want to do?

Comment: @JonSkeet it will not contain never - on start or end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to only perform substitutions in certain cases. In this case, you want to perform a substitution if *either* side of the dash is a non-digit. That's not quite as simple as it might be, but you can use:

```
string ReplaceSomeHyphens(string input)
{
    string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\D)-", "${1} ");
    result = Regex.Replace(result, @"-(\D)", " ${1}");
    return result;
}
```

It's possible that there's a more cunning way to do this in a single regular expression, but I suspect that it would be more complicated too :)

Comment: will this replace - as my code too, or this is part only for XX-XX ?

Comment: @brabertaser1992: I don't understand your comment, but why don't you just try it?

Comment: for example cb100x-08-11r_ didn't work... must be cb100x 08-11r_   also for example how to be with XX-XX-XX ?

Comment: @brabertaser1992: Sorry, there was a typo in my answer - please try again. Basically this replaces any hyphen which isn't surrounded by two digits.

Comment: ok, also it work wrong for example with CB1100 X-11 00-03r must be from CB1100-X-11-00-03r_

Comment: @brabertaser1992: Then you haven't given us adequate requirements. Why would the X-11 not become "X 11"? That doesn't comply with your original question where you only want to keep hyphens surrounded by digits. You really need to think through the precise rules *really thoroughly*. You can't expect us to just guess them.

Answer (score 0):

A very uncool approach using a `StringBuilder`. It'll replace all `-` with space if the two characters before and the two characters behind are not digits.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    bool replace = false;
    char c = text[i];
    if (c == '-')
    {
        if (i < 2 || i >= text.Length - 2) replace = true;
        else
        {
            bool leftDigit = text.Substring(i - 2, 2).All(Char.IsDigit);
            bool rightDigit = text.Substring(i + 1, 2).All(Char.IsDigit);
            replace = !leftDigit || !rightDigit;
        }
    }
    if (replace) 
       sb.Append(' ');
    else 
        sb.Append(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you won't have hyphens at the start of your string then you need to **capture every occurrence of `-` that is preceded by a group of characters which contains at least one letter and zero or many numbers**. To achieve this, use [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your regex.

```
string strRegex = @"(?<=[a-z]+[0-9]*)-";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"ex250-r-ninja-08-10r_";
string strReplace = @" ";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

Here are the results:
[image: Regex execution]